# SQL - Remove the duplicate Results

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name     | surname
------------------
John     |  John
Jessica  |  Madson
```

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE name LIKE '%j%'
    OR surname LIKE '%j%'
```

What I get:

```
John John
John John
Jessica Madson
```

What I want:

```
John John
Jessica Madson
```

How can I get rid of the duplicate results?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, surname
FROM yourtable
WHERE name LIKE '%j%' OR surname LIKE '%j%'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, surname FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%j%' OR surname LIKE '%j%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use group by

```
SELECT name, surname
FROM yourtable
WHERE name LIKE '%j%' OR surname LIKE '%j%'
GROUP BY name, surname
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DISTINCT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/) in SQL Server to get the distinct records only. Apart from this you can also use the [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get the distinct result by assigning the numbers to a result set.

The syntax of `row_number()` is as shown below.

```
ROW_NUMBER ( )   
    OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause )
```

Below is the implementation.

```
Create table TempTable (name varchar(50), surname varchar(50))

Insert into TempTable Values 
               ('John', 'John')
             , ('John', 'John') 
             , ('Jessica', 'Madson')
             , ('Jessica', 'Madson') 
             , ('Suraj', 'Kumar')
             , ('Peter', 'Smith')

Select * from TempTable -- All records.

Select * from(
SELECT name
       ,surname
       ,row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by name, surname) as RN -- For partition
FROM TempTable
WHERE name LIKE '%j%' OR surname LIKE '%j%'
)temp
where RN = 1 -- For Distinct records only
```

The output will look like as shown below:

[image]

You can find the demo at - [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d5f93260d6c6b87aaf5f43fbc24feacb)