# How to implement Two-way ordering in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Tables - 
**Departments** having `Dept_Id`, `Dept_Name` and `Dept_Address` where `Dept_Id` is the primary key and another

**Employees** table having `Emp_Id`, `Emp_Name`, `Emp_Skill` and `Emp_Dept_Id` where `Emp_Id` is the primary key and `Emp_Dept_Id` as the foreign key referencing `Dept_Id of` Departments table.

Now, the task is to find the Department wise Skill. Moreover, the order of the results in `descending order of Department Names` and `ascending order of Skills` *with no duplicates*.

I am stuck at the two way ordering of the results and the removal of the duplicates.

'DISTINCT' was not working for me.
I used a query -

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
    ,Employees e
WHERE d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC;
```

My output was as follows -

```
Training DBA
Training Analyst
Sales Programmer
Finance Analyst
Finance Programmer
Finance Programmer
Finance DBA
Finance DBA
Development Programmer
Development Programmer
```

whereas it should be -

```
Training Analyst
Training DBA
Sales Programmer
Finance Analyst
Finance DBA
Finance Programmer
Development Programmer
```

The input tables were not provided. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say `DISTINCT` "didn't work" but you don't explain why, or show us your attempt. `DISTINCT` *will* work here. Also, like in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038191/how-to-remove-duplicate-results-from-the-result-of-a-query), it's long past time you stop using syntax that was superceded 27 years ago.

Comment: *"If I had known why DISTINCT did not work, I would have answered the question myself."* but you didn't show us your attempt, or explain why it didn't work. "Didn't work" means nothing to us; did you get an error, unexpected results, the server crashed, something else?

Comment: It is an online compiler so I cannot copy the error from there, it just tells me fail. So, I cannot get to know the error. Though "DISTINCT" worked fine on my PC, using dummy table.

Comment: But showing your attempt would have given us insight into the reason, even if you didn't know yourself. You didn't show that, so we have no way of knowing.

Comment: I gave the code I used. Since right click was disabled I could not do anything. And can I delete my previous question? Is that possible,so that this one wont be marked as duplicate?

Comment: Your attempt (in your question) doesn't have `DISTINCT` in it though, so that doesn't explain why `DISTINCT` "didn't work"; unless you're saying the reason `DISTINCT` didn't work is because you forgot to actually put it in the query. If that is the case, this would simply be a typographical error. Anyway, you have your answer, but i do suggest reading the flagged duplicates in future, and not reposting exact duplicates of your previous questions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please open this question?

Comment: There is no reason to. This question is an **exact** duplicate of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60038191/2029983), which, as explained, is a duplicate of [SQL - Remove the duplicate Results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10659860/2029983).

Comment: Then can I remove the previous question? It was not clearly phrased too (Title)

Comment: *You* can delete your own questions, yes. I can vote to delete questions (as a user with a high reputation) but only those with a negative score; so I cannot vote to delete your previous question which this is an exact duplicate of. But none of that changes that this is still a duplicate of the questions outlined in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by d.Dept_Name, e.Emp_Skill` to remove duplicates such like this ones:

> Finance DBA
>
> Finance DBA

And use `ORDER BY d.Dept_Name desc, e.Emp_Skill asc;` to sort by Dept_Name descending and by Emp_Skill ascending.

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
    ,Employees e
WHERE d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
group by d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name desc
    ,e.Emp_Skill asc;
```

Also please join like this:

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
join Employees e on d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
group by d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name desc
    ,e.Emp_Skill asc;
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can also use `DISTINCT` to achieve it. Check my answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040341/9071943

Comment: Hi @ChiradipBhattacharya, I am happy to help...And join too... I always use a good join and group by before a distinct...

Comment: However, in this case, We have not `aggregate`. **The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.**  Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) link to have a better understanding.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are used?!? Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct result.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. BTW, Check my answer below with the explain @jarlh 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040341/9071943

Comment: Hi @jarlh I find this comment offensive and not kind so I think no further discussion is needed. Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't mean to offend you, I just wanted to show another, kinda fun, way to get distinct result.

Answer (score 3):

You should order by 2 columns like this.

```
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC, e.Emp_Skill ASC;
```

And `DISTINCT` to remove duplicated items

**Full query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Dept_Name, e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d, Employees e
WHERE d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC, e.Emp_Skill ASC;
```

**Updated**

You should join 2 tables like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Dept_Name, e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
 INNER JOIN Employees e ON d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC, e.Emp_Skill ASC;
```

**FYI**

You just use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.
This is simply because We have not `aggregate`. While

> The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT,
>   MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) link to have a better understanding.

Comment: Yes, it sure does. Thanks a lot. I learned that either Group by or Distinct can be used to remove the duplicates. Cheers to learning and this awesome community.

Comment: However, in this case, We have not `aggregate`. While **The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.**  Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) link to have a better understanding.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please take a look at @Chiradip Bhattacharya

Comment: Somehow Distinct is not working on the compiler so I used the group by, but surely both work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue in the query has you have it written is not using GROUP BY. It is worth noting the type of JOIN you are using is considered old school, albeit ANSI compliant.

However, if you use JOIN syntax, you will not have to worry about using GROUP BY. JOIN syntax simplifies things significantly, not only in terms of readability but trims the fat in terms of additional syntax like group by in your scenario.

```
SELECT 
     d.Dept_Name
    , e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
INNER JOIN Employees e d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY 
     d.Dept_Name  DESC
     , e.Emp_Skill ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this   :

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
    ,Employees e
WHERE d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC,e.Emp_Skill ASC;
```

Comment: The duplication is not removed, so it did not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query. It will solve the issue

```
SELECT distinct d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
inner join employees e on E.Emp_Dept_Id=d.Dept_Id
   WHERE e.Emp_Skill is not null   
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC, e.Emp_Skill asc
```